# How to handle static factory methods in an inheritance tree

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

I have an inheritance hierarchy where objects can either be constructed normally with some values and some defaults supplied by the various constructors, or can be constructed from a serialized form with all values provided. I'd like to handle construction from the serialized form with static factory methods that I define on each class. Like so:

```js
class A {
  constructor(x: number) {
     this.x = x;
  }

  static fromValues(v: {x: number}) {
    return new A(v.x);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(y: number) {
    super(0);
    this.y = y;
  }

  static fromValues(v: {x: number, y: number}) {
    // what goes here
  }
}

class C extends B {
  constructor(z: number) {
    super(0, 1);
    this.z = z;
  }

  static fromValues(v: {x: number, y: number, z: number}) {
    // what goes here
  }
}
```

The question is: how do I implement those methods? Also, preferably, they would offload some work to super class static factory methods.

Comment: The only way that would work as written is if you create each object independently and create the hierarchy manually by then setting each `__proto__`. You obviously cannot create instances using `new` because you've hard coded the values in the `super()` calls.

Comment: So, I guess maybe the real question is: how should I handle this overall pattern? (ignoring the sample code) Even if I switch the constructor to accept the serialized form and have the static factories generate default objects, I think I still run into the same problem if I want defaults to stay next to the classes that they relate to.

Comment: Please see my answer. Without code this is a _very_ opinionated topic. But you'll see it work below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very opinionated topic (factories in JavaScript). The solution below is provided "in-kind" (written as your question) in order to provide a direct answer without opinion about other methods.

**Note** *the typings are removed because of the limitation of the snippet tool.*

Changes include adding default values in the constructor parameter list. That allows one to remove the hard coded values and optionally provide values for the sub-class constructors. Additionally, defaults are required in your static methods for the same reason.

This allows one to create individual objects or the entire hierarchy either via static factory method OR using the `new` keyword.

```js
class A {
  constructor(x = 0) {
    this.x = x;
  }

  static fromValues(v = {x:0}) {
    return new A(v.x);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  constructor(y = 0, x) {
    super(x);
    this.y = y;
  }

  static fromValues(v = {y:0, x:0}) {
    return new B(v.y, v.x)
  }
}

class C extends B {
  constructor(z = 0, y, x) {
    super(y, x);
    this.z = z;
  }

  static fromValues(v = {z:0, y:0, x:0}) {
    return new C(v.z, v.y, v.x);
  }
}

const a = A.fromValues({x: 3});
const b = B.fromValues({y: 2,x: 3});
const c = C.fromValues({z: 1,y: 2,x: 3});
const nv = C.fromValues();

console.log("A", a);
console.log("B", b);
console.log("C", c);
console.log("No Values", nv);
```